# pom.xml not including dependency after changing compile to implementation

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, pom.xml

I have a gradle library say ABC that is build into aar file and upload to bintray. Before updating gradle version i.e below 3.0 and using compile for all dependency pom.xml contains all dependencies, which works fine.

Now after updating gradle to 3.+ and changes compile to implementation generated pom.xml does not include any dependency information and I found class not found Exception. 
PFA libraries gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation files('libs/Java-WebSocket-1.3.9.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'io.paperdb:paperdb:2.6'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.24465'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.70'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
    implementation('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
        exclude module: "httpclient"
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'servlet-api'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 174
        versionName "1.74"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        group = 'com.abc' // package name
        version = '1.73.2.2' // Change this to match your version number
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }
}

task generateSourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier 'sources'
}

task generateJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath()
            .join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task generateJavadocsJar(type: Jar) {
    from generateJavadocs.destinationDir
    classifier 'javadoc'
}
generateJavadocsJar.dependsOn generateJavadocs
artifacts {
    archives generateJavadocsJar
    archives generateSourcesJar
}

bintray {
    user = 'XXXX'
    key = 'XXXXXX'
    pkg {
        repo = 'abc'
        name = 'com.abc'

        version {
            name = '1.73.2.2'
            desc = 'This is the test build'
            released = new Date()
            vcsTag = '1.73.2.2'
        }

        licenses = ['Apache-2.0']
        vcsUrl = 'https://git.demolibs.in/abc/abc-android.git'
    }
    configurations = ['archives']
}
```

Generated pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>1.73.2.2</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
</project>
```

Also used api instead of implementation but no changes found in pom.xml file. How would you use a library and make gradle download its dependencies?

Thanks

Comment: Have you overcome this issue?

Comment: @ZachBublil Not now. I'm working upon it